# Load Secure Store credentials from SharePoint App

Tags: sharepoint-addin, secure-store

I am writing a SharePoint App (to be hosted in Office 365 and hopefully sold in the SharePoint App Store) and need to be able to load a service account username and password from Secure Store to allow the app to connect to a remote system.

I cannot find any guides on T'Internet about how to connect to the Secure Store Service from the App Web.

Has anyone done this, or know how to do this?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1):

I just want to bump this up as there have been no responses.

Hopefully this doesn't mean that this just isn't possible.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I doubt its possible. If you load credentials to a client the credentials are not secure anymore and thats against the concept of the secure store.